# how to solve netezza SQL Error [1100] [HY000]: ERROR: System is not 'Online'

Tags: netezza, dbeaver

I download netezza emulator and run it on VMware workstation. Then connect via Dbeaver. When I run

`SELECT * FROM TEST1;`

I am getting  SQL Error [1100] [HY000]: ERROR:  System is not 'Online'

how can I solve this error.

Also I cant create new table on emulator when I try to create new table. It doesnt give any error but it also never respons. Dbeaver says execute query and count seconds but no response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add Netezza emulator to vmware virtualize intel vt-x option is not  enabled so it prevents to netezza run properly. You need to enable Virtualize Intel VT-x/EPT or AMD...
Option then reboot netezza vm then netezza will start normally.
if you want to control whether netezza working properly or not you can use

`nzstate`

command

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell, the error message only says that your client (dbeaver) cannot contact the server (Netezza). A couple of guesses:

1. you forgot to turn your emulator on (you mentioned an emulator???)
2. you connect to the server using the wrong IP address and/or port number
3. a firewall is blocking your access (either on you client side, on the server.  or between if it’s not an emulator your are using)

Perhaps Try Ping’ing the server from the client and vise versa (a command prompt of some sort). Then get back to us

Comment: My problem is not about connecting netezza. I already connnected to netezza system .I can see schemas and tables. I just cant run query or list data in tables

Comment: That is Very weird, either the system is online or it’s not..... is your NZ system constantly rebooting or something?

Comment: no, I didnt sense something like that, I mean it is working.When I run netezza emulator Should I run some command in OS to run nettezza or any thing else.Because I didnt do anything with netezza emulator. I just run the emulator in vmware then get the ip adress then connected via Dbeaver. I also try aginity pro but no luck same error

Comment: Very strange. Perhaps disable all firewalls and antivirus and try again ?